# Cannot find click observe Element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have following event on button click

I am unable to find element i.e,Source Element in code

```
Event.observe(Generic_Large_Blue, 'click', 
              moZoltarCurrent.evt_ZoltarOnSubmit.bindAsEventListener(moZoltarCurrent, Item_TextArea, PriceInBox), false);

evt_ZoltarOnSubmit: function(e) {

    var sourceElement = Event.element(e);
    var args = $A(arguments);         

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var sourceElement = Event.element(e);
```

to

```
var sourceElement = e.element();
```